# 500 Internal Server Error after enabling Mongodb with Drupal

Tags: php, mongodb, drupal-modules

In the settings.php you have to put in similar code as below settings.php.

I get an error in the nginx log file showing that it cannot find the path for DrupalMongoDBCache.

*FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DrupalMongoDBCache' not found in /var/www/drupal-test/includes/cache.inc*

If I change the below following path to be exact, then i get a different error:

```
    $conf['cache_backends'][] = '/var/www/drupal-test/sites/all/modules/mongodb/mongodb_cache/mongodb_cache.inc';

    $conf['session_inc'] = '/var/www/drupal-test/sites/all/modules/mongodb/mongodb_session/mongodb_session.inc';
```

FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '
**/var/www/drupal-test/**
drupal-test/sites/all/modules/mongodb/mongodb_cache/mongodb_cache.inc'

**Notice it copies the same beginning path twice. why!? I need php to be able to go to the correct directory in able to not have this 500 internal error problem.
Please help =)**

Copied code into settings.php:

```
    #MongoDB
    $conf['mongodb_connections'] = array(
    'default' => array(                             // Connection name/alias
    'host' => 'localhost',                       // Omit USER:PASS@ if Mongo isn't configured to use authentication.
    'db' => 'tomsadvice-mongodb'                   // Database name. Make something up, mongodb will automatically create the database.
    ),
    );
    include_once('.includes/cache.inc');

    # -- Configure Cache
    $conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/mongodb/mongodb_cache/mongodb_cache.inc';
    $conf['cache_class_cache'] = 'DrupalMongoDBCache';
    $conf['cache_class_cache_bootstrap'] = 'DrupalMongoDBCache';
    $conf['cache_default_class'] = 'DrupalMongoDBCache';

    # -- Don't touch SQL if in Cache
    $conf['page_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;
    $conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;

    # Session Caching
    $conf['session_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/mongodb/mongodb_session/mongodb_session.inc';
    $conf['cache_session'] = 'DrupalMongoDBCache';

    # Field Storage
    $conf['field_storage_default'] = 'mongodb_field_storage';

    # Message Queue
    $conf['queue_default_class'] = 'MongoDBQueue';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

which version do you use? is it the rc2 or dev?

If you are using the dev version, just try the rc2 version.